# Why does sbt fail to run a gui application for the second time?

Tags: scala, user-interface, javafx, sbt

I have a JavaFX based Scala program which can be run both in console mode and gui mode. I can run it in console mode in sbt as many times as I want. However if I run it as a gui application, then for the first time it runs. When I close the window and try to run it for the second time, I get this error message:

```
> > run
[info] Running Start
[error] (run-main-1) java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called more than once
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called more than once
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.application.Application.launch(Unknown Source)
... etc.
```

The application is tested, if I run it as gui from the jar, everything works fine, so this is a problem with sbt.

Comment: As you can see in the Stacktrace, launch gets called more then once. The launch-function can only be called once or an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks, this is it: you have to add 'fork in run := true' to build.sbt.

Comment: @fabian What do you think of this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060425/why-do-colors-disappear-when-i-launch-the-sbt-console-from-a-windows-batch-file

Answer (score 5):

Based on fabian's comment, you have to add

```
fork in run := true
```

to build.sbt.

It works. Tested.